# getting TypeError: o is not a function using Webpack

Tags: angular, webpack

I am getting error "TypeError: o is not a function" while trying to download a file. I suspect this error is due to webpack (using 2.6.1) as without it the code runs fine.

Application has a simple template containing a button and on click of it the file shall download. I have included file-saver in my package.json and have installed the same. Also excluded node modules from all the loaders and tests defined in webpack config.

Tried installing  babel-plugin-add-module-export with no luck.

Appreciate your inputs to resolve this issue.

Below is the code.

```
  public download() {

    let self = this;

    // Status flag used in the template.
    this.pending = true;

    // Create the Xhr request object
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', "Report.pdf", true);
    xhr.responseType = 'blob';

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {

      setTimeout(() => { self.pending = false; }, 0);


        if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
            var blob = new Blob([this.response], { type: 'application/pdf' });
            saveAs(blob, 'Report.pdf');
        }
    };

    // Start the Ajax request
    xhr.send();
}
```

Comment: Issue was resolved by declaring  - "declare module 'file-saver'; " in a separate ts file. 

Then imported -  "import { saveAs } from 'file-saver'; " in the ts file where i am calling to download the pdf file.

Comment: Are you using the file-saver library?